# Bug in "Find and Replace Text" button in an text editor

Tags: java

I have tried this coding for find and replace button in my text editor but is not working .

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String findwhat = new String("");

    String replacewith = new String("");

    String text = ta.getText();        

    findwhat = textField1.getText();
    ln = findwhat.length();

    replacewith = textField2.getText();

    if (ae.getSource() == findButton)
    {
        startindex = text.indexOf(findwhat, i);

        ta.select(startindex, startindex + ln);

        i = startindex + ln;            
    }        
    else if (ae.getSource() == replace)
    {
        ta.replaceRange(replacewith, startindex, startindex + ln);
    }        
    else if (ae.getSource() == replaceall)
    {
        while (startindex + ln != -1)
        {
            startindex = text.indexOf(findwhat, i);

            ta.replaceRange(replacewith, startindex, startindex + ln);                
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me out??

Comment: _"is not working"_ is pretty vague. In what way is it not working? Does it throw an exception? Do nothing when it's supposed to do something? Do the wrong thing? Something else?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not working"? What does this code do? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You need to explain what isn't working. What did you expect it to do, and why? What does it actually do

Comment: its running an infinite loop when replace all button is clicked.

Comment: What is type is `ta`? Where is the `replaceRange()` method?

Comment: @mdewitt - It's a `JTextArea` (a Swing component).

Comment: @Ted Hopp, That's what I was guessing, but I wasn't sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is using a variable `i` that doesn't seem to be defined in the code you posted. But that's neither here nor there. The main problem is that condition `startIndex+ln != -1` is not an appropriate condition for testing loop termination. You also have another issue: the offset at which you want to replace will not be `startindex` each time if the find and replace texts have different lengths. Try this loop instead (untested):

```
startIndex = text.indexOf(findwhat);
int delta = replacewith.length() - ln;
int deltaOffset = 0;
while(startindex != -1) {
    ta.replaceRange(replacewith, startindex+deltaOffset, startindex+deltaOffset+ln);
    deltaOffset += delta;
    startindex = text.indexOf(findwhat, startindex + ln);
}
```

You should also reject a "find and replace" or "replace all" request where `findtext` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem will boil down to this while loop if you have an infinite loop:

```
while (startindex + ln != -1)
{
    startindex = text.indexOf(findwhat, i);

    ta.replaceRange(replacewith, startindex, startindex + ln);                
}
```

Your code is checking the following condition:

```
while (startindex + ln != -1)
```

This condition doesn't make a lot of sense because it says:

```
while the sum of my current start index and the length of the string I 
am searching for does not equal -1, continue searching.
```

You update `startindex` in the while loop, but I don't think it will ever be less than 0. Even if it is set to `0` or `-1`, you `ln` variable is never updated and will always be `> -1` so this will always be true and you will never break out of the loop.

It makes more sense to check each value independent of the other.

Perhaps you need the condition to be:

```
while (startindex != -1 && ln > 0)
```

That says:

```
while I have a startindex to look from (startindex != -1) 
AND 
the string I am looking for is not empty (ln > 0), 
continue to look for the string.
```